# .Net 6 is requiring all non-nullable fields when I try to deserialize JSON

Tags: serialization, json.net, .net-6.0

I'm converting an app from .Net standard to .Net 6, but my controllers are throwing errors if I don't pass in all non-nullable fields.  e.g.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerType { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to pass that object to an action without one of the fields, it throws an error like "The FirstName field is required."  How can I get around that?  I'm using NewtonSoft via the startup file like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
    { 
        options.UseMemberCasing();
    });

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.UseMemberCasing();
    });
```

Comment: Make them nullable or provide the default non-nullable value. Or disable NREs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to open a project configuratuon file (just click on project name in a VS solution explorer) and remove option nullable

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>   <!-- change from enable or remove --> 
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

or if you want to dissable nullabel check only in the controllers actions, you can try another option

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

Comment: The first option didn't work for me, but the second one did.  Thank you!